# Resampling an ndarray by a non time related element

Tags: python, numpy, data-science, numpy-ndarray

I currently have a time series in an ndarray. The time series contains number of sales of a product along with the price of the product. The timeseries data is 24/7 however in off hours the data gets really stochastic because there are less buyers and sellers. What I want to do is resample the time series so that it keeps its current temporal order, but rows that have low numbers of sales get collapsed in to one row, where as a row that has many sales will form multiple rows so that the ndarray that is returned has an equal number of sales in every row. For instance I set number of sales to 1,000, if a row contains 3,000 sales it returns three rows of 1,000 sales, if a row has less than 1,000 sales it gets added to the following row until there are sufficient sales to make a row of 1,000 sales. There are a lot of options available to resample by a time related variable but I'm not finding any for a non-time related variable such as sales. This is the code I have but it doesn't work very well since it lacks the ability to break up rows that are larger than the frequency set so the results aren't equal:

```
def gen_modifiedsales(sales, frequency=100):
    times = sales[:,0]
    prices = sales[:,1]
    volumes = sales[:,2]
    ans = np.zeros(shape=(len(prices), 6))
    candle_counter = 0
    vol = 0
    lasti = 0
    for i in range(len(prices)):
        vol += volumes[i]
        if vol >= frequency:
            ans[candle_counter][0] = times[i]                          # time
            ans[candle_counter][1] = prices[lasti]                     # open
            ans[candle_counter][2] = np.max(prices[lasti:i+1])         # high
            ans[candle_counter][3] = np.min(prices[lasti:i+1])         # low
            ans[candle_counter][4] = prices[i]                         # close
            ans[candle_counter][5] = np.sum(volumes[lasti:i+1])        # volume
            candle_counter += 1
            lasti = i+1
            vol = 0
    return ans[:candle_counter]
```

Ultimately what I'd like is to turn a timeseries that looks like this:

```
Datetime          Price      Volume

2017-12-15 09:30  57.06      3

2017-12-15 09:31  57.04      1

2017-12-15 09:32  57.02      4
```

To something like this

```
Datetime              Price  Volume
2017-12-15 09:05:14   100    57.103306666666796

2017-12-15 11:26:11   100    57.07302666666672

2017-12-15 23:32:03   100    57.14208000000028
```

Or put another way in the city I live we have vendors downtown, they sell things 24 hours a day, if you need to buy 50 pairs of shoes at 10:30 am the price of the shoes will be very fair, there's a lot of competition to sell the shoes, but if you want to buy 50 pairs of shoes at 1:30 in the morning you'll have to pay a lot to buy the shoes since there are far fewer people selling shoes. So during the day time when many shoes are sold the prices tend to be less stochastic, where as at night time they are more stochastic and volatile. In a standard time series based on time alone as frequency night time hours will play a very large role, even though they represent comparatively few sales (after all not many people go downtown to buy shoes in the early morning). By resampling the data for the number of shoes sold the night time hours that are more stochastic and volatile get shrunk, and the day time hours that are less stochastic get increased importance.

Comment: Just to clarify things, you're using NumPy ndarrays for this, not anything from Pandas?

Comment: Yeah I prefer Numpy for this program as it's closer to the C, and gives easier control over dtypes so its not as hard on my computer which is quite old. Edit: Well Numpy is C, so there's that. But yes, I'd prefer to stay away from Pandas. Worse comes to worse as well I can easily compile Numpy but pandas doesn't give me that option.

Comment: Could you provide some data to work with?

Comment: @Chris unfortunately I can't link files. I did give an example of the time series in the question with three columns datetime volume and price. Ultimately though any time series will do, just as long as there's one column that's composed of integers that column can be made to be the new frequency column